# How can I accomplish decorating @Model items more efficiently?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an asp.net mvc3 C# application. It uses a database. The database supports a soft-delete scenario due to requirements. The soft-delete scenario does not cascade. Records which have been flagged as deleted will be showed as grayed out. My issue is with how to do this without having to always surround each display from the model with some html markup and style.

For example:

```
<span @if(m.Box.isDeleted){
 <text>style="background-color:gray"</text>
 }>@m.Box.Name @m.Box.Description</span>
```

I can do that, but look at all the extra markup I have to do to literally every ViewModel object display.

What I would like to do is @m.Box.Name.AddMarkup() or something to that extent. Perhaps I could make a helper which took the item and then returned the correct markup such as

```
namespace place.Markup
public class Markup
{
 public ModelItem(object o, property name)
 {
  //perhaps use reflection so the flag isnt passed all the time
  //create markup with flag conditional decoration
  //return markup
 }
}
```

and then

```
@Markup.ModelItem(@m.Box.Description)
```

I am not sure how I should approach this, or if either of the suggested ways is how others approached this issue. What have you tried to display soft-deleted items? Is there a good tutorial for this somewhere? I couldn't really find much material on this subject.

Please note: the filtering of these objects is not an issue, they are intentionally being displayed and they need to be displayed in a manner which reflects the soft-delete.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @KirkWoll - Sorry for not being explicit enough. **How can I add markup in the view to viewmodel objects based on their value in an efficient manner?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make an htmlHelper based on one or many overloads of DisplayFor

Something like

```
 public static MvcHtmlString DisplayDeleteCheckFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, bool condition) {

     var value = html.DisplayFor(expression).ToString();
     var style=condition ? "style=\"background-color:gray\"" : string.Empty;

     return MvcHtmlString.Create(
         string.Format("<span {0}>{1}</span>", style, value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do it, is to take advantage of CSS.  This is a really rough example.

```
<style>
.isDeleted .showGrayIfDeleted
{
  background-color:gray;
}
</style>
```

In your Controller:

```
if (m.Box.isDeleted)
{
  m.Box.listOfClasses.Add("isDeleted");
}
```

In your view:

```
<div class="@string.Join(" " , m.Box.listOfClasses)">
  <span>blah</span><br/>
  <span class="showGrayIfDeleted">This will be gray if deleted.</span><br/>
  <span class="showGrayIfDeleted">@m.Box.Name @m.Box.Description</span><br/>
</div>
```

By taking advantage of the cascading affect of CSS you only need to apply a single class to a container html element to have all the internal elements have a different background.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done for this is to have a CSS static helper class that is structured like so:

```
public static class ProductCssHelper
{
    public static string IsDeleted(bool IsDeleted)
    {
        return IsDeleted ? "deleted" : String.Empty
    }

    public static string IsAction(bool IsActiveAction)
    {
        return IsAction ? "active-action" : "inactive-action"
    }
}
```

In the razor:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Is Deleted</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
         <tr>
             <td>Today</td>
             <td>Bottle</td> 
             <td class="@(ProductCssHelper.IsDeleted(Model.IsDeleted))">Yes</td>
             <td class="@(ProductCssHelper.IsActive(Model.IsActiveAction))">No</td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

CSS definition not included but this will return the strings for the css classes defined.

I like this method as you can make a CSSHelper folder and inside that have as many helper classes as you need split up by controller or view/area so you have everything in one place.

Not originally my idea but I found the source where I got this idea:
http://www.arrangeactassert.com/asp-net-mvc-view-best-practices-keep-logic-out-of-your-views/